# Courtyard Determination for SMT Trimpot

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, surface-mount, potentiometer, footprint

I would like to use the Bourns PVG3G103C01R00 in a design and am trying to figure out how to determine the courtyard for this part, compliant with IPC-7351B. I do not currently have access to the IPC-7351B standard.

Is there any way to determine this without the standard?

Comment: I'm curious. What is "the courtyard" for a part? What would the standard tell you - or why is there one?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could determine it without having access to the standard.

- Find someone that does have access to the standard and get the information from them. The problem here is that [IPC appears to be using DRM](https://shop.ipc.org/learn-about-license-types-and-document-formats) so there are going to be legal issues there.
- Find a layout/board using that component that you know follows the standard and get the courtyard dimensions from that.

Other than that you'd probably need to just wing it and hope your guess is close enough, or shell out the license fee.

Comment: Yeah, to save any potential hassle regarding DRM, I'll probably just get a hold of the standard. For now (regarding the part in question) I'll just use a conservative estimate. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The courtyard is just the area on the PCB that you want to allow for the part.

I would make the courtyard slightly larger than the overall size of the part, including protruding pins.

When I was making PC boards many years ago, we didn't have courtyards as part of the PCB footprint - it was up to the person doing the layout to determine the space required between parts.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I'm specifically looking to follow the IPC guidelines in this case. I'll probably just get a hold of the standard at some point. Cheers!